# Ideal low pass filter - Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have the following time-continuous system: input signal -->abs block (in the time domain)-->ideal low pass filter block (in the frequency domain)-->output signal. In simulink I make the abs block with the Fcn block. My problem is to get ideal low pass filter with a 3000Hz band and 1 amplitude (linear scale). How could I get it? Maybe I should use Lowpass filter block? In this case what are the right parameters?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal low-pass filter can be represented as (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter):

[image]

So I suggest you use the [Transfer Fcn](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html) block:

[image]

If your amplitude/gain is 1, and your cut-off frequency is 3kHz, then the gain K is 1 and the time constant is:

```
f = 3000;
tau = 1 / (2*pi*f);
```

and your transfer function is:

```
num = 1;
den = [tau 1];
```

Simple!

Comment: Hi @am302. I link signal generator (sinusoidal waveform) to Transfer Fcn to scope. How can I see the transfer function? The scope shows me only the response in the time domain. Thank you very very much.

Comment: I tried to use Spectrum Analyzer, but does not work, it shows the following message: spectrum cannot be displayed for continuous or infinite sample times.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. Simulink is for simulating systems in the time-domain only. You would need to save your data to the workspace and use the [`fft`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) function to go into the frequency domain. You'll need to pay particular attention to the sample time of your data and how to generate the frequency vector when using `fft`. Note this will give you the frequency response, not the transfer function. These are two different things. You know what the transfer function is because you have defined it yourself.

Comment: If I sample the output time-domain signal with the zero order hold block and then I put the output of this block into the input of spectrum analyzer block, I 'll get the output in the frequency domain?